# In IF statement with dates see whether a NULL exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query and i see if the  `AUD_CloseDate` is > than todays date. Now i imagine these would be a NULL somewhere in `AUD_CloseDate` so in this statement i also want to check if there is a NULL value in `AUD_CloseDate` and if there is assign value `1900\01\01`

```
SELECT ([Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + ' of ' + CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(255))) AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST(@Total AS FLOAT) AS [Count]
        FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_CloseDate), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))AND t1.[Status] in ('Open','Closed')
                THEN 'Over Due: '
                ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
                FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
                ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
                WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
                AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] (@LeadAssessor))
                AND t2.AUD_Year = @Year
                AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] (@Quarter)))DER
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325.aspx) function

```
ISNULL(AUD_CloseDate, '1900-01-01')
```

---

You are also:
adding 0 days to date
casting it to char(10)
, then casting again to date... Why?

You can achieve the same result withou these conversions, like this example:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(@a, '2014-01-29 13:50') < GETDATE()
    THEN 'Over Due: '
    ELSE 'On Time: '
END
```

Results 'Over due:'

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(@a, '2014-01-29 15:00') < GETDATE()
    THEN 'Over Due: '
    ELSE 'On Time: '
END
```

Results 'On Time:'

** Now is 13:55 :)

Answer (score 0):

Why about a `ISNULL()` [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) ?

```
ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,'19000101')
```

In you example :

```
SELECT ([Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + ' of ' + CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(255))) AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST(@Total AS FLOAT) AS [Count]
        FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,'19000101')), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))AND t1.[Status] in ('Open','Closed')
                THEN 'Over Due: '
                ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
                FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
                ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
                WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
                AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] (@LeadAssessor))
                AND t2.AUD_Year = @Year
                AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] (@Quarter)))DER
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` is ANSI-compliant.  Same syntax as ISNULL: `COALESCE(t2.AUD_CloseDate,'19000101')`